# Iam trying to use this.history.push to redirect to another page but its not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I used this.context.history.push to redirect to another page but it does not work. Any solution please? 
i am using laravel as a back-end and react js as a front-end now i want to redirect my login page to vendor profile but it not working.
this is my vendorlogin.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { vendorlogin } from '../API/UserAPI'
export default class VendorLogin extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            redirect:false

        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const vendor = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        vendorlogin(vendor).then(res => {
            if (res){
                this.context.history.push('/vp');
            }

            else{
                console.log("login error");
            }
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                        <form noValidate >
                            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">
                                Please sign in
                            </h1>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="email"
                                    placeholder="Enter email"
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="password"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            value="LOGIN"
                            className="button"
                            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                        >LOGIN</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

this is my App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Main/home';
import { Stsignin } from './components/Student/stsignin';
//import { Vsignin } from './components/Vendor/vsignin';
import VendorProfile from './components/Vendor/profile';
import Panel from './components/Vendor/panel';
import Offer from './components/Vendor/offer';
import Vreport from './components/Vendor/vreport';
import Vp from './components/Vendor/vp';
import VendorLogin from './components/Vendor/vendorlogin';



class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Route path='/home' component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path='/stsignin' component={Stsignin}></Route>

        <Route path='/panel' component={Panel}></Route>
        <Route path='/profile' component={VendorProfile}></Route>
        <Route path='/offer' component={Offer}></Route>
        <Route path='/vreport' component={Vreport}></Route>
        <Route path='/vp' component={Vp}></Route>
        <Route path='/vendorlogin' component={VendorLogin}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is my UserAPi.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const vendorlogin = vendor => {
    return axios
        .post('api/vendorlogin', {
            email : vendor.email,
            password : vendor.password
        }, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('usertoken',response.data.token)
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. How is this related to `PHP`?

Comment: sorry iam new here my website backend is on laravel so i added php tag.

Comment: this.history.push is used to change the url **without** redirecting the user to another page.

Comment: so what i should do then?

Answer (score 0):

```
vendorlogin(vendor).then(res => {
            if (res){
                //this.context.history.push('/vp');
                window.location = '/vp';
            }

            else{
                console.log("login error");
            }
        });
```

Comment: try with: window.location.replace("/vp")

Comment: maybe your project have a problem, I'm working with window.location always in my projects and no any problem ! check your project result in console or review your code maybe have a error

Comment: it also not showing anything in the console can you please review my code it's urgent.

Comment: remove form tag from your code and change onSubmit={this.onSubmit} to onClick={this.onSubmit} and try again

Comment: code is working correctly but only redirect part is not working when I try to redirect it doesn't show any  error and doesn't redirect

Comment: did you changed onSubmit to onClick  and removed <form> tag ?

Comment: Yes  I removed it and changed onSubmit to onClick.

Comment: in UserAPi.js remove .then and try again you are using .then in vendorlogin.jsx

Comment: Review: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). I mark your answer for deletion.

Comment: As pointed out in comments, while you seem to have answered OP's question, it's best to combine all updated you've goe through to reach the working state and give a bit more context so others can benefit from your answer too.